# Can't get Eclipse to stop generating tabs in Java source

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to get Eclipse (Kepler) not to generate tab characters in my Java sources, but it's being very stubborn.  What I've done so far: In Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter, clicked on "New" to create a new profile, and typed the creative name "My Profile" as the new profile name.  That name is now showing up as the Active Profile.  I then clicked the Edit button and, on the Indentation tab, set "Tab Policy" to "Spaces only".  Also, in Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors, I checked the "Insert spaces for tabs" box.  Finally, I exited Eclipse and reran it.  The preferences are all still as I set them, and "My Profile" is still shown as the active profile.  But in a Java source, if I go to the end of a line in a method, press RETURN, and add a new statement, the statement begins with two tab characters (I verified this by saving it and looking at the file with another editor).   There aren't any project-specific settings for the project.  What else do I need to do?

More info: I'm finding that it works on sources in some projects but not others.  When I tried it on a project with an "unmanaged profile", and I went into "project-specific settings", changed the profile name so that it would create a new file, and set the Tab Policy, things worked as expected on sources in that project.  But on a project that didn't have project-specific settings set up---no good.

Answer (score 0):

In Preferences, under Java - Editor - Typing, look for the option Tab key adjusts the indentation of the current line" and clear it.  Good luck.

Comment: Didn't help at all--not surprising since I'm not actually using the Tab key.  (There's also an option "Enter key adjusts indentation on the new line".  But I _don't_ want to turn that off; I do want Enter to adjust the indentation, I just want it to be kept in the file as space characters without any tab characters.)

Comment: My apologies -- didn't read that carefully enough.  Perhaps you've found a bug...